# AWS AppSync, filtering lists by @connection

Tags: graphql, aws-appsync

I'm building a project management app with AWS-Amplify. I have a top level type known as a Company:

`type Company 
  @model
  @auth(rules: [
      {
        allow: groups,
        groups: ["SUPERUSER", "ADMIN"],
        queries: [get, list],
        mutations: [create, update, delete]
      },
      {
        allow: groups,
        groups: ["MANAGER, CONTRACTOR, CONSULTANT"],
        queries: [get],
        mutations: null
      }
    ]
  )
{
  id: ID!
  title: String!
  projects: [Project] @connection(name: "CompanyProjects")
}`

It contains a list of projects, another type:

`type Project
  @model
  @auth(rules: [
      {
        allow: owner
      },
      {
        allow: groups,
        groups: ["SUPERUSER", "ADMIN", "MANAGER"],
        queries: [get, list],
        mutations: [create, update]
      },
      {
        allow: groups,
        groups: ["CONTRACTOR", "CONSULTANT"],
        queries: [get, list],
        mutations: [update]
      },
    ]
  )
{
  id: ID!
  company: Company! @connection(name: "CompanyProjects")
  createdOn: String!
  title: String!
  status: CompletionStatus!
  description: String
  documents: [Document] @connection(name: "ProjectDocuments")
}`

How do I properly use filtering during a query such as `listProjects` in order to make sure the current user only gets projects related to the company they are a part of?

Comment: How do associate a user to a company? Is it just whether they're in one of the groups authorized to access that company?

Comment: The companyId is the same as the user's Cognito ID.

Comment: So your Cognito users are really companies, there's no concept of users within companies? Could you share an overview of your resolver setup for companies?